# SEO, Quais as probabilidades de o Googlebot ler esse código Rich Snippets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, seo

Quais as probabilidades de o *Googlebot* ler esse código *Rich Snippets*?

Dicas de como melhorar são bem vindas...

Só posso usar *Front-END*, se não já teria usado um *PHP* para resolver isso.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var url_api_yql = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';

var url_json_tc = 'https://trustedcompany.com/api/v1/company/*?key=f157aee72a787417c20a71ac21708ee8-1b06b0bab68ccc183f78742e3bb8f852';

$.ajax({
  'url': url_api_yql,
  'data': {
    'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="' + url_json_tc + '"',
    'format': 'json',
    'jsonCompat': 'new',
  },
  'dataType': 'jsonp',
  'success': function(response) {
    document.getElementById("rating").setAttribute("content", response.query.results.content.rating);
    document.getElementById("review_count").setAttribute("content", response.query.results.content.review_count);
  }
});

</script>

<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Blog">

    <div property="aggregateRating" typeof="AggregateRating">

        <span id="rating" property="ratingValue"></span>
        <span id="review_count" property="ratingCount"></span>
        <meta property="bestRating" content="5" />
        <meta property="worstRating" content="1" />

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: 42,42% de chance ;P

Comment: É só uma brincadeira ;)